# python: group data within time series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following database:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import strptime

data = {'num': ['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
        'dir': ['IN', 'IN', 'PASS', 'PASS', 'PASS', 'PASS', 'OUT', 'IN', 'IN', 'OUT', 'OUT', 'OUT'],
        'empty': [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False],
        'station': [100, 1, 20, 20, 14, 14, 5, 65, 89, 8, 66, 11],
        'time': [strptime('20180115 00:25', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 00:30', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 01:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 01:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 02:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 02:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 03:33', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 03:33', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 03:34', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 04:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 04:11', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'),
                 strptime('20180115 10:10', '%Y%m%d %H:%M')]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I have to generate a list of the following expected result:

```
   num  empty  station_from  station_to       time_from         time_to
0    B   True           100           5  20180115 00:25  20180115 03:33
1    A  False             1           8  20180115 00:30  20180115 04:10
2    C  False            65          66  20180115 03:33  20180115 04:11
3    B  False            89          11  20180115 03:34  20180115 10:10
```

Explanation:
Those are railway cars where each car is identified by num (i.e. A, B, C)
Those can be either charged or empty (column empty)
The column dir indicates if we have picked in or dropped out that specific car. There can be a lot of other statuses (like PASS in this example) but we are only interested in the IN and OUT statuses
The station column is where the event was occurred
And the time column is when the event was occurred.

I have to group the data between each IN and OUT pairs (or show the track of each of them) and show where and when the activities was happening The difficulty is that this is not a "normal" group by, but a kind of hierarchical, time series based one (in a same day a car can be loaded and emptied several times).

I don't know if pandas is the best structure for that exercise but there are hundreds of millions of records in the DB and performance is critical. (we are preselecting the data based on a specific timeframe)

How to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Depending on the size of the data and the compute resources you have available, you might want to look into a parallelized line sweep algorithm.

Comment: Also, is this a batch or streaming environment? Because approaching this as a streaming problem may make it conceptually easier.

Comment: Well, we might consider that as a batch process, but if the response time is acceptable (below a minute for this and for a dozen of other treatments, but that one has the most of the data) then the whole process will be online (this is preferable), where the user clicks on "Generate" and then he will get the required list

Comment: Regarding the size I might have around 100 000 events (IN, OUT, PASS, etc) per day. The report always generates monthly data (so around 3M records per month) and in the DB we have to keep the data for several years.

Comment: If you generate the report only "on demand" once per month, then that is probably too large of a data set for pandas. (keep in mind that pandas' computational model is wholly in-memory) But unless you have significantly more data than you stated here, then something like dask dask.pydata.org/en/latest/ would definitely be able to handle it. (dask *strongly* emulates the pandas interface, so the learning curve should be very minimal)

Comment: That being said--and bearing in mind that you haven't stated one way or the other whether you're subject to either data access or computational resource constraints "during" each month--it honestly sounds like you're going about this all wrong. Since you know exactly when the report is required, and that is on a regular schedule with a relatively relaxed interval, I would really recommend pre-computing the report in order to achieve *zero* user latency rather than waiting until the very last moment when the user already wants the report.

Comment: OK. I understood. But I still do not know how to come to the expected result without iterating line by line. Which is my initial question. :-) (for the sake of the exercise we might say that list of the records is below 100K or 10K so it will fit within the available memory)

Comment: I cannot precompute because this is a monthly cost analysis report and I have to play with other related cost and revenue data what I have to merge together. The calculation rules are very complicated where I have tons of "it depends" type of rules.

Comment: Moreover, given that the data is continuously arriving throughout the month, and assuming either a sub-day expected transit duration per "group" (implied by the sample data) or at least a generally even distribution of daily "events" over the course of the month, then it should be entirely feasible to incrementally compute the report each day. (with the bonus side effect of having intelligence current down to the day vs. the month)

Comment: If you're simply looking for an algorithm, and assuming that neither external nor distributed approaches are required due to a within-memory data set, then it its definitely feasible. I'll start typing up an answer. (it may take a little while though since my computer is out of commission at the moment, and so I'm limited to just a phone keyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Filter all rows with 'IN'

2) Find first next 'OUT' for each 'IN' with matching *num* and *empty*

```
result = df[df.dir=='IN'][['num','empty','station','time']].rename({'station':'station_from','time':'time_from'},axis='columns')
result[['station_to','time_to']] = result.apply(lambda r: df[(df.index>r.name) & (df.num==r.num) & (df.empty==r.empty) & (df.dir=='OUT')][['station','time']].iloc[0,:], axis=1)

print(result)

  num  empty  station_from                           time_from  station_to  \
0   B   True           100  (2018, 1, 15, 0, 25, 0, 0, 15, -1)           5   
1   A  False             1  (2018, 1, 15, 0, 30, 0, 0, 15, -1)           8   
7   C  False            65  (2018, 1, 15, 3, 33, 0, 0, 15, -1)          66   
8   B  False            89  (2018, 1, 15, 3, 34, 0, 0, 15, -1)          11   

                               time_to  
0   (2018, 1, 15, 3, 33, 0, 0, 15, -1)  
1   (2018, 1, 15, 4, 10, 0, 0, 15, -1)  
7   (2018, 1, 15, 4, 11, 0, 0, 15, -1)  
8  (2018, 1, 15, 10, 10, 0, 0, 15, -1)
```

Comment: Wow! It look nice! I have 2 questions: 1: what is r.name? why is it compared to the index? 2: is not this option (df.empty==r.empty) generates false result if several IN/OUT tracks are both empty or charged? Your solution seems to group them together. Am I right or do I miss something? Actually we should take the first OUT event right after IN regardless of the empty status

Comment: r.name is to access row number when using apply over rows.
I was not sure if empy should or should not match, so added as condition. You may remove (df.emply==r.empty) condition, but then for clarity, might be better to rename it in the resulting table to empty_from